# Angular runtime error calling a function inside the render() loop: 'undefined is not an object (evaluating this.watchLocation)'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, three.js

I am creating an ionic-native Angular app, using three.js and I can't call any function inside the render loop. I have tried using different forms for the watchLocation function, such as including it inside the 'init3D' method, but the full watchLocation() method uses ionic-native plugins which do not work if I declare the function inside the function that calls it.

I have looked at all the other questions on stack overflow, but those methods did not work for this application. I think the problem is in the creation of the 'watchLocation' method or with calling another function within the render loop of a three.js application.

Here is the code (with the changes suggested by @UncleDave):

```
import {Component, Input, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import {STLLoader} from "./stlloader";

import {
  Object3D,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  Mesh,
  WebGLRenderer,
  Vector3,
  SpotLight,
  MeshPhongMaterial,
  Color,
} from "three"
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
 selector: 'three-d',
 templateUrl: 'three-d.html'
 })

export class ThreeDComponent {

  _stlURL: string;

  @Input()
  set stlURL(url: string) {
  this._stlURL = url;
  this.init3D();
 }

  constructor() {
  console.log("threee-3d");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.init3D();
  }
  init3D() {

    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
    ...
    let x=[0]; 
    let y=[0];
    let z=[0];
    render();


    function render() {
      // stats.update();
      this.Location(x,y,z);
      if (group) {
        group.position.x+=x[x.length-1];
        group.position.y+=y[y.length-1];
        group.position.z+=z[z.length-1];
      }

      // render using requestAnimationFrame
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

  }
 Location(_x,_y,_z) {
   alert("hi");
   _x.push(0.01);
   _y.push(0.01);
   _z.push(0.01);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the way 'render' is called, since the definition of 'this' must be passed into it.

Change

```
render();
```

to

```
render(this);
```

and change

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

to

```
requestAnimationFrame(function(){render(scope);});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is near the bottom of `init3D()`:

```ts
render();
let x=[0]; 
let y=[0];
let z=[0];
```

`render()` passes the variables `x`, `y`, and `z` to `watchLocation(_x,_y,_z)` but they're undefined, as they are the only variables that could possibly produce the error message.

The problem is that you're calling `render` **BEFORE** assigning a value to `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Moving the render call to the bottom should fix your issue:

```
let x=[0]; 
let y=[0];
let z=[0];
render();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I have now changed that, but the error still hasn't disappeared and it's still the same 'undefined is not an object (evaluating this.watchLocation)' error